# How to make the slide take 100% versus re-sizing according to browser?

Tags: javascript

I have a fullscreen slideshow page, but the slides don't take up 100% of the background. Instead, they base size off of the browser. I want the slides to take 100% of the background. I THINK I narrowed it down to one function, but I'm not sure and not good with JavaScript yet. Here's the function:

```
    // calculate image size, top and left position
jQuery.fn.superbgCalcSize = function(imgw, imgh) {      

    var options = $.extend($.fn.superbgimage.defaults, $.fn.superbgimage.options);

    // get browser dimensions
    var browserwidth = $(window).width();
    var browserheight = $(window).height();

    // use container dimensions when inlinemode is on
    if (options.inlineMode === 1) {
        browserwidth = $('#' + options.id).width();
        browserheight = $('#' + options.id).height();
    }

    // calculate ratio
    var ratio = imgh / imgw;

    // calculate new size
    var newheight = 0; var newwidth = 0;
    if ((browserheight / browserwidth) > ratio) {
        newheight = browserheight;
        newwidth = Math.round(browserheight / ratio);
    } else {
        newheight = Math.round(browserwidth * ratio);
        newwidth = browserwidth;
    }

    // calculate new left and top position
    var newleft = Math.round((browserwidth - newwidth) / 2);
    var newtop = Math.round((browserheight - newheight) / 2);

    var rcarr = [newwidth, newheight, newleft, newtop];
    return rcarr;

};
```

Let me know if there needs to be more code or even to link to the entire document, as I said I'm not at all experienced with JS and don't know where the problem resides.

*I've tried doing it with CSS, but I get a bug where as it's transitioning to the next image it bleeps the first image's actual size just before displaying the next and it's rather unsleek. Fixing this would also solve my question.

Comment: Hey zartech, I'd recommend making use of [jQuery resize event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) and [jQuery actual](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual), so that your `superbgCalcSize` can adjust if the user was to resize the screen.